# 2D interpolation infinite time to run without any error messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I'm currently working on creating a radial transform of an image in order to do it I use the classical combination of `meshgrid` and `interp2d` function from `scipy` but the code make an infinite time to run and I have to restart the kernel to continue to work on the IPython console. When the matrix is a zero matrix it seems to work but when it starts to be a little bit more complex, the process seems to "crash" in some sense.

Here is the code which reproduces the problem:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata, interp1d, interp2d

x,y = np.linspace(0,50,128),np.linspace(0,50,128)
XX,YY = np.meshgrid(x,y)
test = np.random.random((128,128)) #image
TT = np.arctan2(YY,XX)
RR = np.sqrt(XX**2+YY**2)
interp =  interp2d(RR,TT,test)
```

Any idea? Thank you in advance

Comment: It could simply be that the workload is too heavy for splines to be used. In particular, I am not sure splines are suited to interpolate random data. Have a look at the [Multivariate Interpolation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#multivariate-interpolation).

Comment: I've finally decided to change the method and goes through griddata and this worked perfectly.